# SWT Table resize on Windows and Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, swt

I'm trying to do something that I thought simple, but ... I'm basically adding a resize listener to a SWT Table , eg

```
getTable().addListener(SWT.Resize,  new Listener(){
    int initialSize = getTable().getClientArea().width;
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
        int size = getTable().getClientArea().width;
        System.out.println(""+initialSize+"-"+size+"="+(initialSize-size));
    }
});
```

So if I have a Table with a 1000 initial size and maximizing it I have, for example

1000-1074 = -74

or if instead of maximizing I do a resize with the mouse (in this case shrinking it)

1000-850 = 150

This works well on Linux , but on Windows the listener is invoked throughout the movement and not only at the end of the resize, as Linux does, giving things in only one resize like

```
986-985 = 1
986-985 = 1
985-969 = 16
985-969 = 16
969-965 = 4
969-965 = 4
965-950 = 15
965-950 = 15
950-940 = 10
950-940 = 10
940-937 = 3
940-937 = 3
937-924 = 13
937-924 = 13
924-921 = 3
924-921 = 3
921-920 = 1
921-920 = 1
920-905 = 15
920-905 = 15
905-903 = 2
905-903 = 2
903-902 = 1
903-902 = 1
902-901 = 1
902-901 = 1
```

The objective here is to resize the columns within the table, with some specific calculations, and  what I need is the final size just as in Linux .

I know this behavior are dependent on the OS, but how can I emulate on Windows what it's doing in Linux?

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9366022/1449199).

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll try with that...